# CS193P Assignment 1 π

Tags: ios, swift, cs193p, itunesu

I'm studying CS193P course on iTunesU.  I have a question related to the 1st assignment - Programmable Calculator.  I've attempted to add the π button as described in the lectures and the homework assignment.  However, pressing the π key followed by enter or and operand causes a crash with the message: ***"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"***

```
class CalculatorBrain
{
private enum Op {
    case Operand(Double)
    case NullaryOperation(String, () -> Double)
    case UnaryOperation(String, Double -> Double)
    case BinaryOperation(String, (Double,Double) -> Double)

    var description: String{
        get {
            switch self {
            case .Operand(let operand): return "\(operand)"
            case .NullaryOperation(let symbol, _): return symbol
            case .UnaryOperation(let symbol, _): return symbol
            case .BinaryOperation(let symbol,_):return symbol
            }
        }
    }
}

private var opStack = [Op]()

private var knownOps = [String:Op]() //initialize dictionary

init() {
    func learnOp (op: Op) {
        knownOps[op.description] = op
    }
    learnOp(Op.BinaryOperation("×", *))
    learnOp(Op.BinaryOperation("÷", { $1 / $0 }))
    learnOp(Op.BinaryOperation("+", +))
    learnOp(Op.BinaryOperation("−", { $1 - $0 }))
    learnOp(Op.UnaryOperation("√", sqrt))
    learnOp(Op.UnaryOperation("sin", sin))
    learnOp(Op.UnaryOperation("cos", cos))
    learnOp(Op.NullaryOperation("π", { M_PI }))
}
```

I've been able to force it in the view controller, but know this is a hack:

```
var displayValue: Double{
    get{
        // I don't understand why I had to put this hack in for π
      //  if (calcDisplay.text != "π"){
            return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(calcDisplay.text!)!.doubleValue
       // } else {
       // return M_PI
       // }
    }
    set{
        calcDisplay.text = "\(newValue)"
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = false
    }
}
```

I'm new to Swift / Obj-C.  Can someone please help point me in the right direction to resolve this?

Full source: https://github.com/philnewman/Calculator

Comment: As I understand the assignment, the calculator display will say "3.1415926..." when you press `π`.  All of your other operations put the result on the display, (e.g. `cos` for instance).   `π` works the same way.  It is an operation that puts the result in the display.  This result is the double `M_PI`.  It looks like your display is  `π` which `NSNumberFormatter` can't turn into an `NSNumber`.

Comment: Ah!  Thank you @vacawama Your answer sparked the thought to check viewController.  The π button was mapped to appendDisplay like the number 0-9.  I remapped it to operate like the sin and cos operators and now it works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString` is designed to convert numerical strings into numbers. A "numerical string" is a string whose contents are of the form:

```
([:digit:]+(\.[:digit:]*)?)|(\.[:digit:]+)
```

Where `[:digit:]` is the set of digits `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`.

Essentially, it will only parse numbers from strings whose characters are within `0-9` and an optional `.`.

Because `π` doesn't belong to this set of 10 characters, it is rejected and the `NSNumberFormatter` is unable to parse a number from the string.

Comment: The RegEx is probably at an inappropriate level for a novice. (I'm guessing because of the escaped ".".

Comment: Perhaps. There's no reason to assume that he's a novice across the board, though. I included an extra sentence of explanation just in case.

Comment: Ah!  Thank you @IanMacDonald!!  Your answer sparked the thought to check viewController.  The π button was mapped to appendDisplay like the number 0-9.  I remapped it to operate like the sin and cos operators and now it works properly.  (And it's OK I am a novice)

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func appendPi(sender: UIButton) {

    let x = M_PI
    if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber {
        displayValue = x
        display.text = "\(displayValue)"
    }else {
        displayValue = x
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true
        enter()
    }
}
```

Created a new UIButton function for PI separate from the other functions. Working for me, give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same course, but as I am not yet at the point of separating my MVC (will do that in the next assignment), I can only give you a hint where you go wrong. As it works for me....

Your hack is testing calcDisplay.text as being "π", however at that moment calcDisplay.text should already be 3,14159.
That is what I checked with a println on my working assignment.

So I can show you part of my code which is not optimal for MVC yet:

```
   case "cos": performOperation{cos($0)}
    case "∏": performConstant(operation)

func performOperation (operation: (Double) -> Double) {
    if operandStack.count >= 1 {
        displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast())
        enter()
    }
}

func performConstant (symbol: (String)) {
    switch symbol {
    case "∏": displayValue = M_PI
    default: break
    }
    display.text = "\(displayValue)"
    enter()
}
```

I think it can be more optimal too, but it might help you with finding the bug in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am also doing same course. I did solved "." and "pie" question. See if this help you.

```
@IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!        
        if digit == "." {

            if (display.text!.rangeOfString(".") == nil) {
                display.text = display.text! + "."


            } else {
                //Don't display anything
            }
        } else if digit == "∏" {
            displayValue = pie
        } else {
                if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber {
                    display.text = display.text! + digit
                } else {
                    display.text = digit
                    userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true
                }
        }
    }
```